# What determines the default title for a QMessageBox?

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

I want to change the default `QMessageBox` title to something else, so that I don't have to call `setWindowTitle` for every individual message box.

How is the default window title chosen?

Comment: You may be better off creating a subclass of QMessageBox that sets the window title to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `setWindowTitle` method while you can title when you instance the [QMessageBox](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmessagebox.html#QMessageBox-2) object.

Comment: I know I can pass along the preferred title in the constructor, but it's going to be the same everywhere so I thought I'd be better off changing the default window title to spare me a lot of copy/pasting. Would you suggest using a `const std::string` as the window title for all dialogs? This eliminates the copy/paste work, but it still requires me to indirectly state the window title in the constructor.

Comment: Creating a function is usually a good way to eliminate duplicate code.

Comment: @Pieter First, I am not a C++ pro, so forgive me, all I can suggest is to make function as Mr Roku said and call it when you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do this is to subclass `QMessageBox`, e.g.:

```
class MyMessageBox : public QMessageBox
{
   MyMessageBox()  //<-- default constructor 
   {
    setWindowTitle("Default title goes here"); //QMessageBox function
   }
};
```

Use `MyMessageBox` everywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead add a TARGET in the .pro file. e.g. add this line to the .pro file:

TARGET = MyApp

Thus "MyApp" will be applied both as the executable file name and also as default value for windowTitle of all QMessageBoxes in the entire project.

Comment: You can also set app name with coding: `QApplication::setApplicationName` ( [`QCoreApplication::setApplicationName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop) ) or `QApplication::setApplicationDisplayName` ( [`QGuiApplication::setApplicationDisplayName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationDisplayName-prop) ).

Answer (score -2):

On Windows developing with VC2008 it takes the name from the project. Change the name of the project and it will change the title.

Comment: This is a question regarding Qt.